# Microsoft Entity Framework - In the real world

Tags: entity-framework

I have been developing an inherited a product for the past couple of months that employs Microsoft Entity framework using the persistence ignorant POCO approach. I use a T4 templates to generate my POCOs which include Fixup methods.

My problem is that is just keep running into too many problems that I believe are inherent flaws in the design of Entity Framework. When I fix one thing another issue pops up.

My question is from a truly professional point of view where teams are writing medium to large scale revenue generating applications for desktop and web what are peoples experience and do people actually use Entity Framework in the "real world".

I realize this is a bit of an open question however I would like to survey peoples view to determine if I am fundamentally missing some core concept of EF.

Comment: I've never looked into it, is it anything at all like Hibernate/NHibernate?  That's what I had assumed.

Answer (score 1):

Which version of EF? I'm using 4.1 and it's working just fine. You don't mention exactly *what* you're running into, but If you list specific issues, perhaps we (collectively) can help.

Comment: Using EF 4.0 also looked at the CTP5